# Como logro imprimir un resultado en un input text en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario básico en html en el cual hay dos input text en los que lleno cada uno con una palabra y luego hay un input submit para unirlas, pero por alguna razón no logro mostrar el resultado en el caja de texto

Este es mi codigo:

```js
var palabra1 = document.getElementById('p1');
var palabra2 = document.getElementById('p2');
var frase = document.getElementById('frase');
var error = document.getElementById('error');
error.style.color = 'red';

function validarFormulario() {

}
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var mensajesError = [];

  if (palabra1.value == null || palabra1.value === '') {
    mensajesError.push('Llene el primer campo');
  }
  if (palabra2.value == null || palabra2.value === '') {
    mensajesError.push('Asegurse de tener el segundo campo lleno también');
  }

  error.innerHTML = mensajesError.join(' ,  ');

});

function unir() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').value;
  var resultado = (p1 + p2);

  document.getElementById('frase').innerHTML = p1 + p2;

}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Formulario</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="" id='formulario'>
    <div>
      <label for="p1">Palabra 1:</label>
      <input type="text" id='p1'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="p2">Palabra 2:</label>
      <input type="text" id='p2'>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="unir();" value="unir palabras">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Su frase es :<input type="text" id="frase"></p>


  </form>
  <div id='error'></div>
  <script src="libreria.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cabe destacar que validé los campos de texto y todo pero aún no sé porque no me muestra el resultado en el campo de texto.

Estoy comenzando con javascript y aún estoy sin mucho conocimiento, agradecería mucho la ayuda puesto que requiero resolver esta incognita

Comment: Es por que tienes que controlar el valor del input. Algo como esto -> `frase.value = p1 + p2;` O lo mismo, usando el document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el elemento con `id` **frase** es también un `input`, es decir un elemento de formulario, por tal razón la manera correcta de asignarle un valor no es usando `innerHTML` si no `value`.

```js
var palabra1 = document.getElementById('p1');
var palabra2 = document.getElementById('p2');
var frase = document.getElementById('frase');
var error = document.getElementById('error');
error.style.color = 'red';
function validarFormulario(){

}
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var mensajesError = [];

if(palabra1.value == null || palabra1.value === ''){
   mensajesError.push('Llene el primer campo');
}
if(palabra2.value == null || palabra2.value === ''){
  mensajesError.push('Asegurse de tener el segundo campo lleno también');
}

error.innerHTML = mensajesError.join(' ,  ');

});

function unir(){
  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').value;
  var resultado = (p1 + p2);
  
  document.getElementById('frase').value = p1 + ' ' + p2;

}
```

```css
label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id = 'formulario'>
<div>
    <label for="p1">Palabra 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id = 'p1'>
</div> 
<div>
    <label for="p2">Palabra 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id = 'p2'>
</div>       
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="unir();" value="unir palabras">
<br>
<br>
<p>Su frase es :<input type="text" id="frase"></p>


</form>
<div id = 'error'></div>
```

Si el elemento con `id` **frase** fuera por ejemplo un `span`, si sería correcto usar `innerHTML`.

```js
var palabra1 = document.getElementById('p1');
var palabra2 = document.getElementById('p2');
var frase = document.getElementById('frase');
var error = document.getElementById('error');
error.style.color = 'red';
function validarFormulario(){

}
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var mensajesError = [];

if(palabra1.value == null || palabra1.value === ''){
   mensajesError.push('Llene el primer campo');
}
if(palabra2.value == null || palabra2.value === ''){
  mensajesError.push('Asegurse de tener el segundo campo lleno también');
}

error.innerHTML = mensajesError.join(' ,  ');

});

function unir(){
  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').value;
  var resultado = (p1 + p2);
  
  document.getElementById('frase').innerHTML = p1 + ' ' + p2;

}
```

```css
label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id = 'formulario'>
<div>
    <label for="p1">Palabra 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id = 'p1'>
</div> 
<div>
    <label for="p2">Palabra 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id = 'p2'>
</div>       
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="unir();" value="unir palabras">
<br>
<br>
<p>Su frase es :<span id="frase"></span></p>


</form>
<div id = 'error'></div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias!!!!